# Is it possible to gray out protected branches from the pull request creation UI on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I understand how to restrict merges to certain branches, but is it possible to gray our protected branches out in the "target" dropdown on the DevOps UI for PR creation? This would prevent a lot of wasted time from accidentally creating PRs targeting the wrong/an inaccessible branch.

EDIT: changed the title and description to *graying out* instead of *omitting* protected branches. Inspired by the screenshot in Leo's answer.

EDIT: I want to provide some context for why my team needs this:

Nearly 100% of the time our PRs will target the `dev` branch from a feature branch. The other 1% might be merging from a newer feature branch to an older one. We have locked down our `qa` and `master` branches and only target these in our release cycle PRs, which are exclusively created using the DevOps Service API. Therefore there is literally *zero* value in having `qa` and `master` be selectable in the target branch dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is no such feature. That is what branch policies are for.

Before creating a PR it asks for title, description, reviewers and possibly for a work item to be linked. Then after filling up the information and checking the files & commits that have changes, one consciously takes a decision to click on a button to raise a pull request. This is good enough to stop someone from creating a PR against wrong branch.

If correct policies for branch merge are in place, (like minimum 'n' reviewers must approve, build must pass, work item must be linked, etc.) one cannot complete the PR even if raised.

Even if the PR is raised accidentally, you can still choose to 'abandon' the PR.

What more you can do is rename the concerned branch to something like "{branch name} OBSOLETE" or "{branch name} DO_NOT_USE". Best is to delete such branches altogether. If not, organize your branches using folder. Name the folder something like "OBSOLETE" or "DO_NOT_USE" and keep all the concerned branches under that folder.

Comment: Shridhar, I appreciate your taking time to answer. Similar to my comment on Leo's answer, I don't find such a human error-ridden solution optimal. It isn't "good enough" when you consider that "master" is very often the default target branch on the PR creation UI, and that we _never_ want to manually target that branch.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to omit protected branches from the pull request creation UI on Azure DevOps?

Obviously, Azure devops does not support such a feature, and personally think that MS will not add such a feature in the future.

That's because if we omit protected branches from the pull request creation UI, **then when we want to merge code to these protected branches, we will not be able to find these protected branches in the target branch.** We will no longer be able to merge any code on these protected branches, then the creation of these protected branches will be meaningless.

On the other hand, PR is a very serious matter. It will directly affect the target branch (correct merge or wrong merge to destroy the target branch). So before we do PR, we must be very clear about the target branch we need to merge, **otherwise even if we ignore the protected branch from the target branch, it may still damage other unprotected branches, which will bring great risk.**

**Last but not least**, I understand your needs and want to reduce misoperations caused by too many target branches. I would rather provide you with a good way to avoid it. When creating bracnch, put all the protected branches in a specific folder, like ProtectBranch. So when we are doing PR, the following style will appear in the drop-down menu of the target branch:

[image]

[image]

Using folders to classify the target branch will prevent a lot of wasted time from accidentally creating PRs targeting the wrong/an inaccessible branch.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time answer, Leo. IMO What's missing from the calculus about not allowing the hiding of inaccessible branches is a release cycle pattern: Our team only allows privileged users to merge from environment-named branches (dev/qa/master), and in fact we do this programmatically using the DevOps Service API on our release schedule.

Therefore, forcing users to rely exclusively on their eyeballs instead of restricting their options to a subset of allowed branches leaves us without an ergonomic solution.

Comment: @ZevAverbach, Thanks for your explanation. So, you could not use the workaround that I answered? If yes, I could not think any better solution/workaround for this question. The reasons just like what said in the answer :(.

Comment: Leo, so far as I can tell there's still no way to prevent selection of those `ProtectBranch/`-prepended branches, right? They would still appear in the dropdown. If you have a moment, I'd appreciate any additional thoughts you might have given the extra context I've now provided in my question.

Comment: If `master` and `qa` (our protected branches) could appear in that list but be grayed out, that would be just as good -- if not better -- than my original question about having them disappear entirely. But this isn't possible either, correct?

Comment: @ZevAverbach, I agree with you, grayed out would be better. But just like I said in my answer, this requirement is quite special, there is no solution yet. We could submit this user voice to our main forum for product suggestions: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21. But it may be at a low priority